# Grouping/counting sub-documents while preserving root fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In mongodb, after a few $match and $project, I get the following 2 documents. I'm trying to figure out how to group/count together the list of states for each team in each group of each event.  In short, I need to know how many teams are in each state (0, 1 or 2).  I start out with the following documents.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "event1", 
    "groups" : [
        {
            "_id" : "group1", 
            "wlActive" : true, 
            "teams" : [
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)} 
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "group2", 
            "wlActive" : false, 
            "teams" : [
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)} 
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : "event2", 
    "groups" : [
        {
            "_id" : "group3", 
            "wlActive" : true, 
            "teams" : [
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)} 
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "group4",
            "wlActive" : false, 
            "teams" : [
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(2)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(1)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)}, 
                {"state" : NumberInt(0)} 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm hoping to end up with would be something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "event1", 
    "groups" : [
        {
            "_id" : "group1", 
            "wlActive" : true, 
            "states":[
                {"state":NumberInt(2), count:2},
                {"state":NumberInt(1), count:3},
                {"state":NumberInt(0), count:2}
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "group2", 
            "wlActive" : false, 
            "states":[
                {"state":NumberInt(2), count:2},
                {"state":NumberInt(1), count:3},
                {"state":NumberInt(0), count:2}
            }
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : "event2", 
    "groups" : [
        {
            "_id" : "group3", 
            "wlActive" : true, 
            "states":[
                {"state":NumberInt(2), count:2},
                {"state":NumberInt(1), count:3},
                {"state":NumberInt(0), count:2}
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "group4",
            "wlActive" : false, 
            "states":[
                {"state":NumberInt(2), count:2},
                {"state":NumberInt(1), count:3},
                {"state":NumberInt(0), count:2}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It does not need to be exactly this but as long as I can get a count of each team state and also preserve fields such as "wlActive" for each group. I've seen similar examples on here but I just can't seem to get this one solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just do this with a [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "groups": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$groups",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            { "teams": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$$this.teams",
                "initialValue": [ ],
                "in": {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": { 
                      "$ne": [ { "$indexOfArray":  ["$$value.state", "$$this.state"] }, -1 ]
                    },
                    "then": {
                      "$concatArrays": [
                        { "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$value",
                          "as": "v",
                          "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$v.state", "$$this.state" ]  }
                        }},
                        [{
                          "state": "$$this.state",
                          "count": { "$sum": [
                            { "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$value.count",
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$$value.state", "$$this.state" ] }
                            ]},
                            1
                          ]}
                        }]
                      ]
                    },
                    "else": {
                      "$concatArrays": [
                        "$$value",
                        [{ "state": "$$this.state", "count": 1 }]
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That's pretty complex and basically using [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) "inline" as a substitute for the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline operator.

The [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is the main part of the work as it iterates each array item "reducing" to another array with the "grouped" totals on keys. It does this by looking for the value of `state` within the current reduced result via [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indeOfArray/). When something is not found ( `-1` returned ) it appends to the current result via [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) with a new `state` and `count` of `1`. This is the `else` case.

When something *is found* ( the `then` case ), we remove the matched element from the result array via [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and *concatenate* a new element from the matched index of [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and extract the value using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/). This gives the current `count` of the matched element which is added using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in order to increment the count by `1`.

Of course you can traditionally just do that with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$groups" },
  { "$unwind": "$groups.teams" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "gId": "$groups._id",
      "wlActive": "$groups.wlActive",
      "state": "$groups.teams.state"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": -1, "count": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "gId": "$_id.gId",
      "wlActive": "$_id.wlActive",
    },
    "teams": { "$push": { "state": "$_id.state", "count": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "groups": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id.gId",
        "wlActive": "$_id.wlActive",
        "teams": "$teams"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Here [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is used to *"flatten"* the array content into separate documents. You do this down to the `teams` level and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the *compound key* which identifies *uniqueness* down to the `state` level.

Since all the document detail is part of the initial [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) key, you remove the level of *"uniqueness"* so `teams` becomes an array using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/). In order to get back to the original document form, another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is done on the original `_id` value for the documents and the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) reconstructs the `groups` array.

That form is probably *"easier"* to comprehend, however it does take considerably longer to run and takes more resources. The first form is *optimal* since you don't actually need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) within an existing document, and you generally should avoid [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) unless absolutely necessary. i.e Grouping `state` across *all documents* is necessary, but within a single document it is not.

Either way basically returns the same result:

```
{
        "_id" : "event1",
        "groups" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "group1",
                        "wlActive" : true,
                        "teams" : [
                                {
                                        "state" : 2,
                                        "count" : 2
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 1,
                                        "count" : 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 0,
                                        "count" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "group2",
                        "wlActive" : false,
                        "teams" : [
                                {
                                        "state" : 2,
                                        "count" : 2
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 1,
                                        "count" : 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 0,
                                        "count" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "event2",
        "groups" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "group3",
                        "wlActive" : true,
                        "teams" : [
                                {
                                        "state" : 2,
                                        "count" : 2
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 1,
                                        "count" : 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 0,
                                        "count" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "group4",
                        "wlActive" : false,
                        "teams" : [
                                {
                                        "state" : 2,
                                        "count" : 2
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 1,
                                        "count" : 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "state" : 0,
                                        "count" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

---

For what it's worth, since this is not really *"aggregating"* anything across documents you can just as simply return all the data and "aggregate" the array items within client side code.

As a mongo shell example:

```
db.collection.find().map(doc => Object.assign({}, doc, {
  _id: doc._id,
  groups: doc.groups.map(g => Object.assign({}, g, {
    _id: g._id,
    wlActive: g.wlActive,
    teams: ((input) => {
      var obj = input.reduce((o, e) => 
      (o.hasOwnProperty(e.state)) ? 
        Object.assign({} , o, { [e.state]: o[e.state]+1 })
        : Object.assign({}, o, { [e.state]: 1 }),  {});
      return Object.keys(obj)
        .map(k => ({ state: parseInt(k), count: obj[k] }))
        .sort((a,b) => b.state - a.state);
    })(g.teams)
  }))
}))
```

Comment: It works!  I'm impressed @neil-lunn!  To me this is like solving a Ribik's cube.  I guess when you have enough experience it makes sense but I'm just not there yet.  Thanks for the quick answer! :)  Just out of curiosity, do you have a reference to a good tutorial on grouping?

Comment: @LucChevalier It takes practice but you get used to it over time. The [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the official documentation is full of usage examples you can learn from. Also there is "this very site" and you can always search within the [aggregation-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregation-framework) tag for various examples in answers.

Comment: @NeilLunn, considering your multiple options, the question that often comes to my mind is, should I put the load on the MongoDB server (I'm using MLab) or my node js server (hosted on Heroku) or just return lots of data and do this parsing on the client side (basically eating more bandwidth).  I never know the implication of doing more processing on the MongoDB server vs on the node js server.  Is it preferable to just retrieve the data and then aggregate using js?  Is there a way to decide?

Comment: @LucChevalier That's a very valid point and very much the reason for the very last example of a "client side" approach. It really comes down to the question *"Do I save considerable bandwidth by **not** sending the whole document back to the client?"*. If your array content that is being *reduced* contains 100's of items and you are returning *multiple documents* containing these long arrays, then it's likely better to run the aggregation in the pipeline. If they are all relatively short, then it's likely better to do in *in the client* instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn A problem that I have with this query is that if there are no teams in the teams array, that group is not returned at all... and if none of the groups of an event have teams, the event itself is not returned.  I think this is a good case for parsing the data in JS on the node server instead of a group query on the MongoDB server.  Unless you have a way to specify that you also want groups with 0 teams?  (Aha! Curve ball! ;) )

Comment: @LucChevalier No idea what you are talking about since all examples here produce identical output and have near identical logic (i.e Inline `$reduce` cannot *"merge object keys"* like `.reduce()` so we replace array items instead). If you have another question then please [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as comments are not really intended as an ongoing discussion of new things that come up