# How to count size of sub-sub internal list in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

I'm new to MongoDB. I don't know much MongoDB queries. One query which I'm unable to find. "Get all students list and count of addressList".

Document:

```
{ _id: 123, students:
    [
      { 
        studentId:987,
        studentName:"####",
        addressList:[
                 {
                   addressId:678,
                   addressName:"XXXXXXXX"
                 },
                 {
                   addressId:679,
                   addressName:"XXXXXXX"
                 }
               ]
      },
      {
        studentId:988,
        studentName:"####",
        addressList:[
                 {
                   addressId:680,
                   addressName:"XXXXX"
                 }
               ]
      }
    ]  
}
```

Response:

```
 {
   students:[
               {
                 studentId:987,
                 studentName:"#####",
                 addressCount:2,
              },
             {
               studentId:988,
               studentName:"#####",
               addressCount:1
             }
         ]
}
```

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992837/grouping-counting-sub-documents-while-preserving-root-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$students"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      students: {
        $push: {
          addressCount: {
            $size: "$students.addressList"
          },
          studentId: "$students.studentId",
          studentName: "$students.studentName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but while running above query I getting the following error- 
{
 "message" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 16945,
 "codeName" : "Location16945",
 "name" : "MongoError"
}

Comment: Please share mongo version it should be above 3.6.

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.6.3